# How to handle MySQL's Foreign Key Error in Php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I was testing foreign keys in MySQL. The objective is to prevent the entry of an `id` into `table2`, that does not exist in `table1`. I was hoping that using `foreign keys` would simply result in a row not being inserted, but it seems to throw up this huge error. How do I handle this in PHP? Is there a way to make MySQL simply not insert the row and return no rows returned?

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`wp-db`.`borrowed`, CONSTRAINT `borrowed_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`employeeid`) REFERENCES `employee` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)' in C:\web\apache\htdocs\dev\foreign.php:10
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 C:\web\apache\htdocs\dev\foreign.php(10): PDOStatement->execute()
>
> #1 {main} thrown in C:\web\apache\htdocs\dev\foreign.php on line 10

Answer (score 4):

use try catch

```
try { 
    $pdo->exec ("QUERY WITH SYNTAX ERROR"); 
} catch (PDOException $e) { 
    if ($e->getCode() == '23000') 
        echo "Syntax Error: ".$e->getMessage(); 
}
```

Read [`PDOStatement::errorCode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorcode.php)

taken from [Return Code list](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jenut/ch08_06.htm)

> The SQL-92 standard defines a set of SQLSTATE return codes. SQLSTATE
>   is defined as a five-character string, where the leftmost two
>   characters define the error class, and the remaining three characters
>   define the error subclass. Some database vendors may extend these
>   return codes; classes beginning with the numbers 5 through 9 and
>   letters I through Z are reserved for such implementation-specific
>   extensions. The SQLSTATE code for a particular JDBC action can be
>   retrieved via the `getSQLState()` method of `SQLException`