# PhP check if data is empty on MySQL UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

So, basicaly I have an input where the user can choose the employee, but I need to give a **warning** or an **error message** if the user inputs an employee that does not exist on the DB, I can simply check if the user's input is empty with

```
if (empty($id_colaborador)) {
    $id_colaboradorError = 'Introduza o colaborador!';
    $valid = false;
}
```

But I need to check if the user's input does not exist too, how can I do that ?

My query looks like this:

```
if ($valid) {

    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "UPDATE ativos 
                SET ativo = ?, comentario = ?, data_aquisicao = ?,
                    localizacao = ?, fabricante = ?, modelo = ?, 
                    imei = ?, numero_serie = ?, ativo_sap = ?, 
                    anexo_a = ?, evento = ?, data_evento = ?,
                    id_colaborador = (SELECT id_colaborador 
                                      FROM colaboradores 
                                      WHERE nome = ? LIMIT 1
                                      ) 
            WHERE id_ativo = ?";

    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($ativo,$comentario,$data_aquisicao,
                        $localizacao,$fabricante,$modelo,
                        $imei,$numero_serie,$ativo_sap,
                        $anexo_a,$evento,$data_evento,
                        $id_colaborador,$id)
                );
```

And when the user inputs an employee that does not exist the page gives me an error (obviously)

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails...

And I need to replace that error with a simple "**User not found, please select one that already exist.**" or something like that

Comment: All that variables are my fields from the DB

Comment: U can see it through the query

Comment: So, you just need to implement a `try{}catch{]` block right?  And sniff for that `1452` code, right?

Comment: Are you sure that `$id_colaborador` contains valid data for a `nome`

Comment: Like I said Yesterday, do a SELECT on the `colaborator` using the `nome` to find if your employee exists. If it does Do the Update (using the found `id`). If not generate an error message and send it

Comment: @RiggsFolly is this the right hammer? https://stackoverflow.com/q/18526019/2943403

Comment: @mickmackusa Looks fairly good to me

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes I'm sure, you can see that it's getting the data from `id_colaborador` using the `nome` here: `... SELECT id_colaborador 
                                      FROM colaboradores 
                                      WHERE nome = ? LIMIT 1   ...`

Comment: `WHERE nome = ?` is using `$id_colaborador` as the data for that parameter! I would expect a `nome` column to be a string and an `$id_colaborador` field to be a number (___an ID___) so either your ___naming convension is bad___ or you are ___using the wrong data as a `nome`___

Comment: Yes, `nome` is a string and `id_colaborador` is an ID (PK) and the user should input the `nome` and side by side it will show the `ID` of the employee that the user input, that way if I have two or more employees with the same name the user can select which one he want

Comment: It would be easier if you just showed a dropdown list of employee's. Then the user could never attempt anything with an invalid employee

Comment: Well it could.. but I have more than 300 employess that's why I'm using an autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you say you need to check first whether the user exists with a separate select query something like :

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM colaboradores  WHERE nome = ?");
$stmt->execute([$id_colaborador]);
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();


if ($count > 0) {
    //Update
} else {
    //throw error message
}
```

That way your first step is to check the db if the user exists and then (if the count is above 0 meaning that exists) run the update query.

Comment: THanks for your awnser, but now it doesn't gives an error but skips and not update it and dont show any error message :/

Comment: print_r the $count what does it show? like `print_r($count); die();` Also please make sure that `$id_colaborador` have the value that nome requires cause i id indicated that it is an integer generally and nome should be a string.

Comment: Nothing :/ or maybe I'm doing it wrong.. I put my query inside the `if($count > 0)`

Comment: yes but before that print the $count to see it's value. If the query is wrong then count will never be higher than 0. As i said the query is filtering by name(nome) are you sure you want it that way? Maybe the where clause should be the id because i am pretty sure that `$id_colaborador` is an integer

Comment: Yes the ID is the PK, but that way the user can not input the `name` instead of the `ID`...

Comment: Then the query needs to be changed. In the where clause of my query you need to pass the name that the user puts not an id. Modify it as such.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185474/discussion-between-pr1nc3-and-carlos-santiago).